# Sorting varchar column

Tags: mysql

I have a Chapters Columns and it has values like

```
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
Chapter 11
Chapter 12
Chapter 3
Chapter 4
```

When I order it it displays as

```
Chapter 1
Chapter 11
Chapter 12
Chapter 2
Chapter 3
Chapter 4
```

I need like this

```
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
Chapter 3
Chapter 4
Chapter 11
Chapter 12
```

Comment: Were you able to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is called `Natural Sort`. can you try this? but there is no perfect way to natural sort.

```
SELECT col
FROM tab
ORDER BY LENGTH(col), col;
```

even prefix is not same, sort can be done if modified like this (am I right? I think 1st query works well in OP's case. but not sure below query is general)

```
SELECT col
FROM tab
ORDER BY col, LENGTH(col), col;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you always have "Chapter " and after that a number, you can try this:

```
SELECT chapters 
FROM tab1 
ORDER BY LENGTH(chapters), chapters
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/749b6/1)</kbd>